# Kendo RadioButtonBuilder does not contain a definition for 'Size'

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

At my company we use Kendo for all our UI components. We don't have a ton of Radio Buttons and I was told they want to make them smaller, however, when I try to add the .Size (as according to the docs)

`@(Html.Kendo().RadioButton().Name("radioBtn1").Checked(varChecked ?? false).HtmlAttributes(new { @name = "radioBtn1" }).Label("Label").Size(ComponentSize.Large))`

I get this error
Error   CS1061  'RadioButtonBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'Size' and no accessible extension method 'Size' accepting a first argument of type 'RadioButtonBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
and this error
Error   CS0103  The name 'ComponentSize' does not exist in the current context

Does anyone have any ideas?

These are the nuget packages related to Telerik that I have installed in the project:

- Telerik.Reporting version 14.0.20.115
- Telerik.ReportViewer.Mvc version 14.0.20.115

Thank you!

I tried reading the docs from Telerik and I submitted a support question to them, but haven't been able to figure out why this isn't working for me.

Comment: What version of Kendo/Telerik.UI are you using?

Comment: That is a good question, and I dont know where to find that info. Could you help me out? I don't see it in any of my references or anything. In my content/kendo folder there is a folder named 2020.3.1118. Is that the version?

Comment: The small code sample you posted indicates that you are using the MVC wrapper for Kendo, so you should have another nuget package reference similar to the Telerik Reporting ones you noted, but it should be named something like Telerik.UI.for.AspNet.Mvc5. That package reference in Visual Studio would show the version. However, the 2020.3.118 you listed is likely the version, so next would be to check why you don't have the package reference.

Comment: Yea, I was surprised I dont see any Telerik.UI in any of the references or dlls (I didnt set anything up). But that 2020.3.118 if I upgrade that, I should have what I need?